# C# ASP.NET Core - Generic method to return property of type T

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I want to return a property of Type T passed to my generic function but I cannot find a way to accomplish it. I would like to do something like this (that would actually compile and work):

Let' say I have this properties of type DbSet as follows:

```
public DbSet<Colegio> Colegios { get; set; }
public DbSet<Clase> Clases { get; set; }
public DbSet<Persona> Personas { get; set; }
public DbSet<Profesor> Profesores { get; set; }
public DbSet<Alumno> Alumnos { get; set; }
```

And I want my generic method to return those DbSets which are of type T:

```
public DbSet<T> GetDbSetByType<T> ()
    {
        // Code to return one of the DbSet which match the type T 
        // So If T is of type Colegio it will return the DbSet<Colegio> Colegios which is declared above.
    }
```

So I could call it like this:

```
DbSet<alumno> alumnos = _contextDB.GetDbSetByType<Alumno>()
```

And get DbSet Alumnos property.

Any tip or better way to do this is welcomed.

Thank you all.

Comment: what should `return Colegios` do? You surely need an **instance** of that class which you want to return. You cannot return a **class**. Anyway a **generic** method that swiches on **specific** type isn´t really *generic*, is it? You probably don´t even need the switch, just do `return new T()` and add the `new()`-constraint to your method.

Comment: If you're using `DbContext`, [there's already](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext_Set__1) a `DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()` method that does exactly this.  E.g `var personas = _context.Set<Personas>()`.

Comment: return Colegios is not returning the class Colegio, Colegios is the property whose signature is public DbSet<Colegio> Colegios { get; set; }. And I know that a generic method which is switching is not generic but that's the thing, I want to do a generic method which will return the correct DbSet depending on the type that's been passed to the method<T>.

Comment: @Oliver I'm using DbContext yes, but I don't have .Set() function. I'm using .NET 5, should I use another .NET Core version?

Comment: Okay I think I might found out the solution, it was as easy as this: public T GetById<T>(int ID) => (T) _contextDB.Find(typeof(T), ID);